# Formatting python dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary, formatting

I am having an issue formatting my dictionary right now in key value pairs.

```
x = [('the', 709),  ('of',342), ('to',305)]
```

does anyone know how I can get this to show

```
the:709
of:342
to:305
```

I just cannot figure out the split.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x` is a list, not a dictionary. You can iterate over list items and unpack tuples this way:

```
>>> x = [('the', 709),  ('of',342), ('to',305)]
>>> for a, b in x:
...     print '%s:%s' % (a, b)
... 
the:709
of:342
to:305
```

If you want to make a dictionary from `x`, just pass it to [`dict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-dict):

```
>>> d = dict(x)
>>> d
{'of': 342, 'the': 709, 'to': 305}
>>> for a, b in d.iteritems():
...     print '%s:%s' % (a, b)
... 
of:342
the:709
to:305
```

Note that dictionaries are unordered collections - don't expect items in order that you have inside `x`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a dictionary

```
x = {"the": 709, "of": 342, "to": 305}
for key, value in x.iteritems():
    print key + ": " + str(value)
```

If you're using a list of tuples:

```
x = [('the', 709),  ('of' ,342), ('to', 305)]
for a, b in x:
    print a + ": " + str(b)
```

---

Unless you need them in order, **you should use a dictionary for this kind of thing** (Python dictionaries are unordered).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a dictionary, it should look like:

```
x = {"the": 709, "of": 342, "to": 305}
```